# Normal distribution comparing 3 or more variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let's say we had 3 students about to run race and their previous run times each follow a normal distribution,

- $X \sim N(10, 2)$
- $Y \sim N(14, 3)$
- $Z \sim N(5, 1)$

Where $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

I want to know if it is possible to work out the probability that $X$ will run the fastest time?

I feel like the question boils down to $P((X>Y) \cap (X>Z))$. I can work out $P(X>Y)$ and $P(X>Z)$  by creating a new distribution for each and just calculating mean and variance. But I am struggling to go this extra step to determine the probability that both scenarios are true.

Comment: What is $A$? $~~$

Comment: Sorry that was a typo it was meant to be X

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$ are the density function sof $X,Y$ and $Z$ then $$P((X>Y)\cap (X>Z))$$ $$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_z^{\infty}\int_y^{\infty} \phi_1(x)\phi_2(y)\phi_3(z) dx dydz$$ $$+ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int_{-\infty}^{z}\int_z^{\infty} \phi_1(x)\phi_2(y)\phi_3(z) dx dydz$$

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate as to why those are the bounds for each integration?

Comment: @Sam You want to integrate over the region $\{(x,y,z): x>y, x >z\}$. If $y >z$ this reduces to the single condition $x>y$ and if $y <z$ this reduces to the condition $x>z$. So split the integration w.r.t $y$ into the parts $y>z$ and $y <z$. Rest should now be clear.

Comment: Yes, that is crystal clear really appreciate the explanation